# How can I create a "go to page" form?

Tags: html, forms, hyperlink

I have a content page with multiple pages, they are being shown as website/index?content=home&page=1, 2, 3 etc...

but now I want to create something like a text field button that links to the number the visitor puts in like Go to (21) and it redirects to website/index?content=home&page=21.
I want to do it without any mysql or databank entries
I appreciate any help!

Comment: If your page has no server-side script such as ASP.NET, etc. Then this would be a JavaScript question. I'm not that good at JavaScript and so I can't answer off the top of my head. But it's pretty straight forward to read the value of a text box and then open a page that incorporates that value.

Answer (score 3):

```
<form action="website/index" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="content" value="home" />
<label>Go to<input type="number" name="page" /></label>
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Comment: didn't think of that. +1 - This is probably the better option.

Comment: is there a way to set the size of the box?

Comment: You can set the width with CSS for example: `<input type="number" name="page" style="width: 20px;"/>`

Comment: it works in dreamweaver but when i display it in a brower the box is huge again

Answer (score 1):

```
Response.Redirect("~/index.apsx?content=home&page="+GotoPage.ToString());
```